# k'th largest element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool findNthMax(double arr[], int len, int n, double& nth_max)
{

sort(arr, arr+n);


//Counter
int c = 1;

//Initialize nth max
nth_max = arr[0];

//Loop in the array while the count is less than (n)
for (int i = 0; i < len && c < n; i++)
{

    if (arr[i] != nth_max)
        c++;


    nth_max = arr[i];

}

return nth_max;

}

int main()
{
int n;
double arr[10];
double y;

cout << "The random array elements are:" << endl;

srand((unsigned)time(0));
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    arr[i] = (rand()%100);

    cout << arr[i] << ' ' ;

}

cout << endl;
cout << "Input a positive integer n: " ;
cin  >>  n ;

if(n>10)
cout << "The nth largest value does not exist." << endl;
else
cout << "The nth largest value is: " << findNthMax(arr, 10, n, y) << endl;

return 0;

}
```

EDIT: the function returns false if the nth largest value does not exist; the first parameter is the  input array; the second parameter is the array size; the third parameter is used to pass the value of n to the function; the last 
parameter is nth largest value being found.

The main function generates an array with 10 double random elements (in the range [0, 99]. It prints out those 10 elements. Prompt a user to enter a 
positive integer n, then print out the nth largest value in the 
array.

How ever my outputs shows that nth largest: 1 when n = 2

Comment: Why are you returning bool?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're doing. But if you pass array of length n then there should always be up to m=n "largest" values. If larger number is given than number of elements you can return false. For the other cases simply sort the array and return the value indexed my value m (m-largest).

Comment: You're printing the boolean return value, not the result (which is confusingly written to `y`, while the return value is meaningless, and certainly doesn't match the description). I think you want to sort the whole array, not just the first `n` elements, and probably in the opposite order. In general, you want to step through the code in a debugger to see what it's actually doing and how that differs from what you want it to do.

Comment: First why your function's return type is bool. Second why you are sorting first n elements of the array only? And lastly what does the loop do?

Comment: [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing `c` to 2 after `if arr[1] != nth_max`.  This means that `c !< n`, so you're `for` loop exits after 2 loops through.

You need to sort the entire array, b/c you're missing the case where you could have 8 duplicates before the 2nd max, for instance { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 2, 8, 8, 8 }.

```
sort(arr, arr+len);
```

You should start your `for` loop at the end of the array...

```
nth_max = arr[len-1];    
for (int i = len-1; i >= 0 && c < n; i--)
```

Then also run the function before outputting the variable `y`:

```
findNthMax(arr, 10, n, y);
cout << "The nth largest value is: " << y << endl;
```

Comment: this almost actually works but like you said im having problems with the sorting of array.

Comment: @friedrojak the sort call was added to the answer.  You pretty much had it.